# Date naipulation in Perl

Tags: perl

My script is passed a date parameter  in the format `YYYYMMDD`, like for example `20130227`.  I  need to check whether it's a Monday.  If yes then  I need to retrieve the previous four days date values otherwise I should  retrieve the two previous days' date  values and store them in array.

For example if the parameter is  `20130227`  and it's a Monday, then I need to store `('20130227' '20130226'  '20130225' '20130224')`  in an array.  If it's not a Monday then I  need to  store  only `('20130227' '20130226')`  in an array.

What perl  function can I use  for doing this?  I am using perl on solaris 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all standard Perl commands are listed in the standard Perl list of commands. This is a big confusion for beginners and the main reason you end up seeing beginners use a lot of `system` commands to do things that could be done directly in Perl.

Many Perl commands are available if you include the *Perl Module* for that command. For example, you want to copy a file from one place to another, but there's no Perl `copy` command listed as a standard function. Many people end up doing this:

```
 system ("cp $my_file $new_location");
```

However, there is a standard Perl module called `File::Copy` that includes the missing copy command:

```
 use File::Copy;

 copy ($my_file, $new_location);
```

The `File::Copy` module is included with Perl, but you have to know about modules and how they're used. Unfortunately, although they're a major part of Perl, they're simply not included in many Perl beginner books.

I am assuming your confusion comes from the fact you're looking for some command in Perl and not finding it. However, the [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module is a standard Perl module since Perl 5.10 that is used for date manipulation. Unfortunately, it's an *object oriented* module which can make its syntax a bit strange to users who aren't familiar with Object Oriented Perl. Fortunately, it's really very simple to use.

In object oriented programming, you create an *object* that contains your data. The object itself cannot easily be displayed, but contains all of the features of your data, and various *methods* (basically subroutines) can be used to get information on that object.

First thing you need to do is create a *time object* of your date:

```
 my $time_obj = Time::Piece->strptime("20130227", "%Y%m%d");
```

Now, `$time_obj` represents your date. The `20130227` represents your date string. The `%Y%m%d` represents the format of your string (`YYYYMMDD`). Unfortunately the `Time::Piece` documentation doesn't tell you how the format works, but the format characters are documented in the [Unix strftime manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).

Once you have your *time object*, you can query it with all sorts of method (aka subroutines):

```
if ( $time_obj->day_of_week == 1 ) {
    print "This is a Monday\n";
}
```

Read the documentation and try it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Will go through the Time::Piece module

Answer (score 1):

The generic toolkit for handling dates in Perl would be the `DateTime` module. It comes with a huge range of date parsing choices to get your strings formats in and out, and can easily query e.g. day-of-week.

A more lightweight, fast and recommended alternative might be `Date::ISO8601` - your formats are quite close to that ISO format, but you would need to be willing to do a bit of manipulation on the variables e.g. `my ($yyyy, $mm, $dd) = ( substr($d, 0,4), substr( $d, 4, 2 ), substr( $d, 6, 2 ) );` will grab the year month and day strings from your examples to feed to the module's constructor.

Please give these at least a try, and if you get stuck post some code on your question. Once you have some attempted code in the question, it is much quicker for someone to answer by filling in just the bits you don't know - you probably know a lot more about the solution you want than you think!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not keen on helping someone who appears to have made no effort to them themselves. So I'm not going to give you an answer, but I'll suggest that you look at the Time::Piece module (a standard part of Perl since version 5.10). And, in particular, its `strftime` method.

That should be enought to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Will go through the Time::Piece module.